# $_FILES not working with ajax submit in woocommerce checkout

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am try to upload file on woocommerce checkout page but I am not able to upload file. I have also try to get value using `print_r($_FILES)` in create_order function in class-wc-checkout.php file but it will return blank array
When I have remove class checkout from checkout form then it will working fine (without ajax submit)

I want to submit form without ajax but I need ajax remain on checkout page because I have add some extra price using ajax (update price without refresh)

My ajax call to add extra fee.

```
   jQuery('#PageCount').change(function () {
            var state = jQuery('#PageCount').val();
            var current_price = jQuery('#carttot').val();
        var data = {
            action: 'woocommerce_apply_state',
            security: wc_checkout_params.apply_state_nonce,
            state: state,
            current_price: current_price
          };
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            success: function (code) {
           console.log(code);
                if (code === '0') {
                 jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                }
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and php code or woocommerce hooks to add extra fee

```
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_apply_state', 'calculate_per_page', 10);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_apply_state', 'calculate_per_page', 10);

function calculate_per_page() {
    if (isset($_POST['state'])) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $weight = WC()->cart->cart_contents_weight;
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $current_price = $_POST['current_price'];
               $val =  $current_price * $state -$current_price;
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['val'] = $val;
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee');

function woo_add_cart_fee() {
    session_start();
    $extracost = $_SESSION['val'];
    WC()->cart->add_fee('Per page charges:', $extracost);
}
```

And my function to upload file..

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ($_FILES['avatar']['name']) {
 if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
                  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
               }
               $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 

               $path = $upload_dir['path']; 

              $fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]; 
              $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
              $pathAndName = $path."/".$fileName;
              $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
              update_post_meta( $order_id, 'uploaded_file_to_translate', $_FILES['avatar']['name']);

  if ($_POST['billing_output_to_send']) 
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'How do you want your translation sent to you?', esc_attr(htmlspecialchars($_POST['billing_output_to_send'])));
  if ($_POST['PageCount']) 
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'How many pages are in your documents?', esc_attr(htmlspecialchars($_POST['PageCount'])));


         } 
}
```

How it will possible?

Comment: I have added my ajax call to add extra fee and if I will remove ajax from checkout then my custom ajax call will not work

Comment: Sorry, I added my upload code now

Comment: @user5227171 did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES` you can not get it at `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta hook`  because of woocommerce `serialize` the form and submit form throw ajax,
as we know that form serialize can not submit files requests. but I have two solutions for doing this may be it work for you.

1. You can use a plugin woocommerce upload file in the checkout. you can easily find it on google

**But if you want to upload custom files then you can use this**

2. when `onchange file` fire an ajax and push file array in `session` when user checkout, get the files from the session and upload to the directory, and then destroy your session.

```js
$('.fileupload').change(function(e){
    var action = 'update_session_files';
    e.preventDefault();  
  
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('action', action);
    
        var files = $('input[name="file"]')[0].files[0];
    
        fd.append('billing_artist_headshot', files);
       
             $.ajax({
               url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: fd,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response){
                       
                    },
                });
            });
```

and ajax action

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_session_files', 'update_session_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_session_files', 'update_session_function' );
function update_session_function(){
session_start();

 $_FILES['billing_artist_headshot'];
// upload your file here with Wordpress and get the id.
}
```